# Alternative to mysql_field_name in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I found this great function that converts MySQL queries into a XML page, and it looks like exactly what I need.  The only problem is that it uses MySQL, but that's not supported anymore, and it turns out one of the functions used isn't in MySQLi.  Does anyone know of an alternative to `mysql_field_name`?

Here's the function that I found

```
function sqlToXml($queryResult, $rootElementName, $childElementName)
{ 
    $xmlData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\" ?>\n"; 
    $xmlData .= "<" . $rootElementName . ">";
 
    while($record = mysql_fetch_object($queryResult))
    { 
        /* Create the first child element */
        $xmlData .= "<" . $childElementName . ">";
 
        for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($queryResult); $i++)
        { 
            $fieldName = mysql_field_name($queryResult, $i); 
 
            /* The child will take the name of the table column */
            $xmlData .= "<" . $fieldName . ">";
 
            /* We set empty columns with NULL, or you could set 
                it to '0' or a blank. */
            if(!empty($record->$fieldName))
                $xmlData .= $record->$fieldName; 
            else
                $xmlData .= "null"; 
 
            $xmlData .= "</" . $fieldName . ">"; 
        } 
        $xmlData .= "</" . $childElementName . ">"; 
    } 
    $xmlData .= "</" . $rootElementName . ">"; 
 
    return $xmlData; 
}
```

With the part in question is

```
$fieldName = mysql_field_name($queryResult, $i);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, I guess the most similar would be:

```
$fieldName = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i)->name;
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field-direct.php

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the @trakos answer:

If you prefer the lazy way

Since mysql_field_name is removed in PHP 7, try the alternatives, mentioned in the docs:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-name.php

If you want the same-named function, try to implement this one:

```
function mysqli_field_len($result, $i) {
    $properties = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i);
    return is_object($properties) ? $properties->name : null;
}
```